# When testing a Salesfore LWC component which is better if (boolean Value === true) vs if (boolean Value === 1)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, unit-test, lwc-jest

My test data has a value in it like this:

```
   "preSelected": 1,
```

amongst other values which are part of a mock of apex returned data.

In my js code I test against this value like this:

```
   for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
       this.foundIds.push(this.data[i].id);
       if (this.data[i].preSelected === true) {
           my_ids.push(this.data[i].id);
       }
   }
```

this works perfectly for the lwc component in the actual system but when writing the LWC test the last line is not executed.
In order for the jest test to execute that last line i need to modify last IF test to be like this:

```
   if (this.data[i].preSelected === true  ||  
       this.data[i].preSelected === 1 ) {
```

Is there a better way to get the test to pass as the test for 1 is just there for the test class.
thanks

Comment: Just curious, why won't you change `"preSelected": true` in Apex class?

Comment: I am.  Here is my apex code:
` // for any search results returned, determine if they are already on the case and mark as such
  for (QueryResultWrapper qrw : results) {
        for (CaseToContractAccountRelationship__c caRel : caseCaRels) {
               if (qrw.id == caRel.ContractAccount__c) {
                   qrw.preSelected = true;
               } `

Comment: value is defined as boolean in apex  
`@AuraEnabled public Boolean preSelected;`

Comment: Is it possible to leave if-condition like just `if (this.data[i].preSelected)`?

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave your if-condition just like `if (this.data[i].preSelected)` without trying to compare it to any value.